# log in script problrm in oophp mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, doophp

I have used the fooling code for log in but it is not logging me in to admin index page.Could anyone help me?

1. Session.php file

   ```
   /**
   * Session class
   */



    class Session{
       public static function init(){
           session_start();
       }

       public static function set($key, $val){
           $SESSION['$key'] = $val;
       }

       public static function get($key){
           if (isset($_SESSION['$key'])) {
               return $_SESSION['$key'];
           }else{
               return false;
           }

       }

       public static function checkSession(){
           self::init();
           if (self::get('login') == false) {
               self::destroy();
               header("Location:login.php");
           }
       }

       public static function destroy(){
           session_destroy();
           header("Location:login.php");
       }

       }
   ```
2. Format.php file

   ```
   public function formatDate($date){
       return  date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($date));
   }

   public function textShorten( $text , $limit = 400){
       $text = $text . " ";
       $text = substr($text, 0, $limit);
       $text = substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, ' '));
       $text = $text . ".....";
       return $text;

   }

   public function validation($data){
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripcslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;

   }

   }
   ```
3. Database.php

   ```
   public $link;
   public $error;


   function __construct()
   {
       $this->connectDB();
   }

   private function connectDB(){
       $this->link = new mysqli($this->host,
   $this->user,$this->pass,$this->dbname);
       if(!$this->link){
           $this->error = "Connection failed" . $this->link;

       }

   }

   //Insert Data
   public function insert($data){
   $insert_row = $this->link->query($data) or die($this->link->errror.
   __LINE__);
       if($insert_row){
           return $insert_row;
       }else{
           return false;
       }
   }

   //Select Data
   public function select($data){
   $result = $this->link->query($data) or die($this->link->errror.
   __LINE__);
       if($result->num_rows >0){
           return $result;
       }else{
           return false;
       }

   }

   //Delete Data
   public function delete($data){
       $delete_row = $this->link->query($data) or die($this->link->errror.
    __LINE__);
       if($delete_row ){
           return $delete_row;
       }else{
           return false;
       }

   }

   }

   ?>
   ```
4. header.php of admin index.php

   Admin Panel
        -->
        -->
       </script> -->
       
       
       </script> -->

   ```
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet"href=
   "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com
   /bootstrap/3.3.6 /css/bootstrap.min.css"
       integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5    WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME 1fgjWPGmkzs7"crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

   <link rel="stylesheet"href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="styles/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"   
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container"><!--1. Container area begins -->
   <div class="row"><!--2 Header area begins -->
   <div class="col-md-12 h_decoration">
     <div class="header">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-1 heder_logo">
           <img src="images/img/logo.jpg"alt="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-8 header_title">
             <h3>Dreanland of Web Development Project</h3>
             <p>www.dreanmland.com. A promising web 
              developer organisation for you all.</p>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 login_logout ">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
             <?php
               if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "logout")
               {Sesssion::destroy();
               }
             ?>
               <div class="logger pull-right">
                 <ul>
                   <li><i class="fa fa-user-circle"aria-hidden="true">
     </i> Hellow Bishwajit &nbsp; ||  &nbsp; </li>
              <li><a href="?action=logout">
     <i class="fa fa-sign-out"aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout </a></li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class=" h_links pull-right">
           <ul>
             <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="">User</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Change Password</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   </div><!-- 2/ Header area ends -->
   ```

Comment: can you post your error logs? have you tried var_dump(), error_reporting(E_ALL);, or any other debugging methods?

Answer (score -2):

There will be need another function at Session.php file "Like"

public static function checkLogin()